# Facebook Live API - Pairing Encoder - Invalid parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working my way through setting up a paired encoder for Facebook Live. Following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/getting-started/#pairing and  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-encoder/. I have been able to register the encoder and get a FBID, and broadcast_id.  I am stuck at the "status:capture" point.  Facebook send the {action:"capture"} response, but when the encoder responds with the video parameters, I get an error {message    (#100) Invalid parameter, type  OAuthException, code    100} I am currently testing using the Graph API Explorer, but I get the same error with my scripts.  I am not sure what parameter is invalid...

Thanks!

Here is what I am sending (with a valid token):

status  CAPTURE

broadcast_id    **************

cap_streaming_protocols rtmp

cap_audio_codecs    aac

cap_video_codecs    h264

input_video_width   1920

input_video_height  1080

input_video_framerate   30000/1001

input_audio_samplerate  48000

input_audio_channels    2

Here my code snippet:

```
     $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "//graph.facebook.com/"+fbid+"?access_token="+fbToken,
        data: {
           'status':'CAPTURE',
           'broadcast_id': broadcast_id,
           'cap_streaming_protocols': 'rtmp',
           'cap_audio_codecs':'aac',
           'cap_video_codecs':'h264',
           'input_video_width': '1920',
           'input_video_height': '1080',
           'input_video_framerate': '30000/1001',
           'input_audio_samplerate': '48000',
           'input_audio_channels': '2'
        },
    }).done(function(response){
           console.log(response);
           $('#link').html(response);
    });
```

Comment: Did you get this solved? I'm having the exact same problem right now...

Comment: @kiw , no luck yet.  I've put this project on hold for now, hopefully someone will have an answer, or the docs will be updated before I need to have this done.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this today. As of this moment, cap_streaming_protocols=rtmps is the only value it accepts. If you need the rtmp url you can get that using the broadcast_id on the live_video edge. The rest looks like it should work.